# How can I keep this text in the middle even in mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple form that asks for login details, but I want it to also be mobile friendly. It works great with desktops, but on mobiles it shifts a little bit to the right. I want the text to be exactly in the middle, like on pc.
Pic of the site on mobile:[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Teretulemast</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      </head>
      <body style="display:block; padding: 0; width: 80%; margin-left: 40%; overflow:hidden; position: relative;">
        <form>
          <h1 style="">Sisse logimine</h1><br />
          <p style="">Kasutajanimi: </p><input style="height: 25px;"type="text" name="username"/>
          <p style="">Parool: </p><input style="height: 25px;" type="password" name="password"/><br />
          <input style="" type="submit" value="Logi sisse" name="Sisesta"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Tagasi" name="back"/>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Check out https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Hi, I think one of the best options is to use medias queries : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Requ%C3%AAtes_m%C3%A9dia/Utiliser_les_Media_queries
go on youtube and search some tutorial if you aren't familiar with, it's a veryyyy usefull feature :).

Comment: You have your element set at 80% width, and a margin-left of 40%. That puts the center of the element at 10% to the right of the center. Try 'margin: 0 auto;' instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn more about flex box: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Teretulemast</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body style="display:flex; padding: 0; width: 100%; overflow:hidden; align-items: center; justify-content: center">
    <form>
      <h1 style="">Sisse logimine</h1><br />
      <p style="">Kasutajanimi: </p><input style="height: 25px;"type="text" name="username"/>
      <p style="">Parool: </p><input style="height: 25px;" type="password" name="password"/><br />
      <input style="" type="submit" value="Logi sisse" name="Sisesta"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Tagasi" name="back"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to set the `<form>` to `display:inline-block` and set `text-align:center` on its container. That ensures that the form's content dictates it's width and that it's always horizontally centered on the page.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 .2em;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>Sisse logimine</h1><br />
  <label>Kasutajanimi:<br><input type="text" name="username"></label>
  <label>Parool:<br><input type="password" name="password"></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Logi sisse" name="Sisesta">
  <input type="submit" value="Tagasi" name="back">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these css styles on the form

```
form{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 200px;
 padding:30px;
 border:1px solid grey;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}
```